# Define JSON boolean type as RESTful body type in RAML

Tags: json, boolean, raml

I have a RAML file that is including a custom BooleanValue json schema as its return type for a method.

BooleanValue.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Boolean value",
    "description": "If lookup or update in success",
    "type": "boolean"
}
```

Service.raml snippet:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Service API
version: 1.0
mediaType: application/json
schemas:
  - BooleanValue:  !include model/BooleanValue.json

<... snip ...>

/resource:
  /{name}:
    patch: 
      responses: 
        200:
          body:
            schema: BooleanValue
            example: true
```

I'm convinced that defining the BooleanValue schema is not needed, but I can't find a sample of how else to indicate a JSON boolean type is the return value.

Can this be done?  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RAML 1 you can do this:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Service API
version: 1.0
mediaType: application/json
/resource:
  /{name}:
    patch: 
      responses: 
        200:
          body:
            description: If lookup or update in success
            type: boolean
            example: true
```